# How to change "X minutes ago via SO AND SO" in the Facebook API for Android

Tags: android, facebook, api, upload, photo

I am trying to change the name that appears in the sentence

**"X minutes ago via NAME_HERE"**

when you upload a picture in the Wall on Facebook (using the Android API).

I think that it has to do with the Facebook ID. However, I don't want to create another Facebook ID just to change that name. Is it possible to change that name WITHOUT CREATING ANOTHER FACEBOOK ID???

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and edit the name of your app in the basic settings page

Comment: Hi lgy. Thanks for replying. The thing is that I cannot do that, because I have the same application deployed to some different clients. The name should be customized according to the client, so that's why I would like to do that programatically (or via XML), without having to create 1 ID for each client.

Comment: You'll need to use one app ID per client then, the app name is unique to an app ID

Comment: And then, since automatic app creation is impossible, have fun manually creating new app for each client ;). And in every app remember to add privacy policy, change email address (unless you want to get app reports to your private email), set proper favicon, logo, url, domainm and probably many different awesome things! It's FUN(sic!). Trust me, I've been there...

Comment: Most (if not all) app settings can be changed directly in the API once you have the app secret, it's just creation and the Open Grapt settings that need to be changed manually. Your two basic options are use one app per 'app' (if that makes sense), or use an app ID that's suitable generic. If this is a mobile app you'd probably need to use a different app ID per client-app anyway or you'd have issues with single sign on and the android marketplace links

Comment: Hi Igy and chester. I see, that's what I was thinking... I will have to create one Facebook ID per application just to change that name then. I wish the Facebook API was more robust.

Thank you for your responses! I accepted your answer now.

Comment: Now I am struggling on how to change the LINK of the "so and so" part. Is it possible?

As default, the link always point to my Facebook application page, but I want to send the user to another page if it clicks in "SO AND SO".

Comment: no that's not possible - it will bring users to your app's website